# CentOS Running process not responding to kill signals and not context switched

Tags: linux, centos, process, kill, signals

An updatedb process on my linux server is not responding to kill signals. (kill -9 or SIGSTOP)

```
[root@chroot-1 ~]# ps auwx | grep -i 4505
root      4505 99.5  0.0  59544  1256 ?        RN   09:43 112:04 /usr/bin/updatedb -f sysfs?rootfs?bdev?proc?cpuset?binfmt_misc?debugfs?securityfs?sockfs?usbfs?pipefs?anon_inodefs?futexfs?tmpfs?inotifyfs?eventpollfs?devpts?ramfs?hugetlbfs?mqueue?selinuxfs?rpc_pipefs?autofs
root      5727  0.0  0.0  61212   836 pts/2    S+   11:36   0:00 grep -i 4505
[root@chroot-1 ~]# kill -9 4505
[root@chroot-1 ~]# kill -9 4505
[root@chroot-1 ~]# kill -9 4505
[root@chroot-1 ~]# ps auwx | grep -i 4505
root      4505 99.5  0.0  59544  1256 ?        RN   09:43 112:16 /usr/bin/updatedb -f sysfs?rootfs?bdev?proc?cpuset?binfmt_misc?debugfs?securityfs?sockfs?usbfs?pipefs?anon_inodefs?futexfs?tmpfs?inotifyfs?eventpollfs?devpts?ramfs?hugetlbfs?mqueue?selinuxfs?rpc_pipefs?autofs
root      5729  0.0  0.0  61212   840 pts/2    S+   11:36   0:00 grep -i 4505
[root@chroot-1 ~]# kill -s SIGSTOP 4505
[root@chroot-1 ~]# ps auwx | grep -i 4505
root      4505 99.5  0.0  59544  1256 ?        RN   09:43 112:31 /usr/bin/updatedb -f sysfs?rootfs?bdev?proc?cpuset?binfmt_misc?debugfs?securityfs?sockfs?usbfs?pipefs?anon_inodefs?futexfs?tmpfs?inotifyfs?eventpollfs?devpts?ramfs?hugetlbfs?mqueue?selinuxfs?rpc_pipefs?autofs
root      5731  0.0  0.0  61212   840 pts/2    S+   11:36   0:00 grep -i 4505
```

`From top`

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND  

 4505 root      34  19 59544 1256  548 R 100.0  0.0 108:49.08 updatedb
```

Why is the process constantly in R state? Why is it not being context switched and moved to wait queue? Why is this process not responding to kill signals that cannot be handled(like `SIGKILL` or `SIGSTOP`)

Comment: Any NFS mounts or network filesystems? I/O can block in the kernel, and cares not for `KILL` signals.

Comment: Does it have a parent process? `ppid`? Try killing the parent process if it has one. A process starts its life in an R "running" state and finishes after its parent reaps it from the Z "zombie" state.

Comment: @thrig If it is blocking on IO, then it should ideally go to uninterruptable D state, which is not happening.

Comment: @JonKittell Yes, it had. THe updatedn was triggered by crond, which was its parent process. I tried to kill it, and it was reaped by init.

Comment: Is it changing process ids? Or is it always the same process id?

Comment: Try `kill -9`, if that doesn't work then reboot the system.

Comment: Or try signal 30. `SIGPWR 30 Power failure restart (System V)`

Comment: @JonKittell It is the same process ID. Before rebooting, I wanted to know why it is not responding to kill signals like `sigkill and sigstop`.

Comment: Try to connect with strace -p <pid> and see what it does.